# rails overriding/scoping views for multi tenancy app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, multi-tenant

I'm wondering how I can scope my views.  I want to have custom themes depending on the organization, I can use render directly on the show/index actions... and that works, but I would have to override a lot of actions on my application.  I would prefer to do it on the controller level and tried doing it with `prepend_view_path` but it didn't except the variable as undefined.

```
class EditionsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :current_organization
  prepend_view_path "app/views/#{current_organization.slug}/editions" #doesn't work

  def show
    @edition = Edition.find(params[:edition_id])
    @page = @edition.pages.first
    render template: "#{current_organization.slug}/editions/show" #works
  end
```

Any ideas?

Also tried: (with same error)

```
append_view_path(File.join(Rails.root, "app/views/#{current_organization.slug}"))
```

Answer (score 3):

> custom themes depending on the organization

Surely it would make more sense to define custom `layouts` & `CSS` rather than entirely different view sets for each company?

--

I would personally do this:

```
#app/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", controller_name ... %>
```

This will give me the ability to style the different pages as per the theme. Obviously a constriction on what you want, but I hope it shows how you could modularize your controllers etc

--

If you wanted to create different "themes" (IE having a completely different view structure per tenant), you'll want to use the [`prepend_view_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/prepend_view_path) helper, as described [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/prepend_view_path):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   prepend_view_path("views/#{current_organization.slug}")
end
```

Comment: almost, except that the current_organization helper method errors out as `undefined`, if I put Organization.first.slug instead it works fine.  But it appears the prepend is being loaded before the current_organization helper

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `editions` in `prepend_view_path`

```
prepend_view_path "app/views/#{current_organization.slug}"
```

Make sure what the way was added. If it doesn't add `before_filter`